# MVC Bundling with HTTPS IE7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https, internet-explorer-7

I have successfully implemented MVC bundling for my MVC application.  There is one problem with the run time which runs under HTTPS.

I am sure there is a problem because when I switch the debug field to false the user gets the warning message "This page contains secure and nonsecure items.  Do you wish to proceed?

I know that I can turn this prompt off using the security setting in IE.  I would like to know if there is something I can do to the application so that bundled scripts and styles come through the secure pipe.

Comment: you need to check in the browser which elements/files come through HTTP, then you change those in your application so that they are accessed via HTTPS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for this suggestion. I figured out that the problem was coming from modernizr-1.7.js 
The strange thing was that this problem only occurs when modernizr is bundled. I removed modernizr because we don't really need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the `Scripts.Render` helper to include the bundle it will use the same HTTP scheme as the one used to request the main page. So if the main request was done over HTTPS then this helper will generate a `<script>` element using HTTPS. You could use the `Net` tab of FireBug to see which resources are served through HTTP and HTTPS and be able to isolate the problem.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I figured out that the problem was coming from modernizr-1.7.js r v2.6.1.

Comment: The strange thing was that this problem only occurs when modernizr is bundled.  I removed modernizr because we don't really need it.

Comment: Unless the page request originates as http and then a rewrite rule sends it to https. In this instance Srcipts.Render doesn't work. Looking for a solution to this.