# Log browser settings, rendered html on client's browser.

Tags: asp.net, logging, elmah, client-side-scripting

We regularly receive reports about different client side errors especially our users seeing "this page contains secure and nonsecure items" warnings when using our site. We know that the various screens in our site contains all secure elements. If the client receives a "this page contains secure and nonsecure items" warning, is there a way to log 
a. the rendered html on the client's browser.
b. The browser settings that the client might have. eg: in Internet Explorer, Tools=> Internet Options=> Security Tab => the "Custom Level" button => Display mixed content option.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no way to track IE alerts, but as described here "[MVC Bundling with HTTPS IE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357106/mvc-bundling-with-https-ie7)" you could have some contents or scripts in your page that come from an **HTTP** request (not secure), and some others coming from **HTTPS** (secure).

Are you maybe providing pages from HTTPS and you have some scripts include from HTTP?